# Footer rendering at top of page -- Rails

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, render

I have a site based off of [Michael Hartl's tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org), but unfortunately I'm having a problem with the rendering of a specific one of my pages. The page is called /games/new

Here is the code `Games/new.html.erb`:

```
<h1>New game</h1>

<div class='div_left'>
    <h2>Custom Game</h2>
    <%= render 'fantasy' %>
</div>


<div class='div_right'>
    <h2>Upcoming Games</h2>
    <%= render 'real' %>
</div>
```

Here is the code for `custom.css.scss`:

```
@import "bootstrap";

/* mixins, variables, etc. */

$grayMediumLight: #eaeaea;

@mixin box_sizing {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* universal */

p.big {
    font-size:200%;
    display:inline;
}

div.div_left {
    width:400px;
    float:left;
}

div.div_right {
    width:400px;
    float:right;
}

div.div_left_small {
    width:175px;
    float:left;
}

div.div_right_small {
    width:175px;
    float:right;
}

div.div_center {
    width:400px;
    float:right;
}

div.inline {
    display:inline
}

html {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

body {
  padding-top: 60px;
}

section {
  overflow: auto;
}

textarea {
  resize: vertical;
}

.center {
  text-align: center;
  h1 {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
}

/* typography */

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  line-height: 1;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 3em;
  letter-spacing: -2px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 1.7em;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: $grayLight;
}

p {
  font-size: 1.1em;
  line-height: 1.7em;
}


/* header */

#logo {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
  font-size: 1.7em;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  padding-top: 9px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1;
  &:hover {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
}

/* footer */

footer {
  margin-top: 45px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  border-top: 1px solid $grayMediumLight;
  color: $grayLight;
  a {
    color: $gray;
    &:hover { 
      color: $grayDarker;
    }
  }  
  small { 
    float: left; 
  }
  ul {
    float: right;
    list-style: none;
    li {
      float: left;
      margin-left: 10px;
    }
  }
}

/* miscellaneous */

.debug_dump {
  clear: both;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 45px;
  @include box_sizing;
}

/* sidebar */

aside {
  section {
    padding: 10px 0;
    border-top: 1px solid $grayLighter;
    &:first-child {
      border: 0;
      padding-top: 0;
    }
    span {
      display: block;
      margin-bottom: 3px;
      line-height: 1;
    }
    h1 {
      font-size: 1.4em;
      text-align: left;
      letter-spacing: -1px;
      margin-bottom: 3px;
      margin-top: 0px;
    }
  }
}

.gravatar {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.stats {
  overflow: auto;
  a {
    float: left;
    padding: 0 10px;
    border-left: 1px solid $grayLighter;
    color: gray;
    &:first-child {
      padding-left: 0;
      border: 0;
    }
    &:hover {
      text-decoration: none;
      color: $blue;
    }
  }
  strong {
    display: block;
  }
}

.user_avatars {
  overflow: auto;
  margin-top: 10px;
  .gravatar {
    margin: 1px 1px;
  }
}

/* forms */

input, textarea, select, .uneditable-input {
  border: 1px solid #bbb;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  @include box_sizing;
}

input {
  height: auto !important;
}

#error_explanation {
  color:#f00;
  ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0 0 18px 0;
  }
}

.field_with_errors {
  @extend .control-group;
  @extend .error;
 }

 /* users index */

.users {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  li {
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 10px 0;
    border-top: 1px solid $grayLighter;
    &:last-child {
      border-bottom: 1px solid $grayLighter;
    }
  }
}

/* microposts */

.microposts {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 10px 0 0 0;

  li {
    padding: 10px 0;
    border-top: 1px solid #e8e8e8;
  }
}

.content {
  display: block;
}

.timestamp {
  color: $grayLight;
}

aside {
  textarea {
    height: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
  }
}
```

Here is the code for `_fantasy.html.erb`:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@game) do |f| %>
    <div class='form-inputs'>
        <%= f.error_notification %>

        <% choices = Team.all.map { |team| team[:name] } %>

        <%= f.input :first_team_name, collection: choices, label: 'Team 1' %>
        <%= f.input :second_team_name, collection: choices, label: 'Team 2' %>

        <%= f.input :user_guess, collection: [ 1, 2 ],
                                 label_method: lambda { |obj| "Team #{ obj }"},
                                 value_method: lambda { |obj| obj },
                                 label: 'Who do you think will win?',
                                 as: :radio_buttons%>
        <%= f.input :game_type_id, :as => :hidden, :input_html => { :value => 1 } %>
        <br>
        <%= f.submit 'Simulate!', class: 'btn btn-large btn-primary'%>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Here is the code for _real.html.erb:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@game) do |f| %>
    <div class='form-inputs'>
        <% reference_games = Game.where(game_type_id: 3).map {
            |game| [ "#{ game.first_team_name } vs #{ game.second_team_name }", game.date_played ] }    %>

        <%= f.input :team_names, collection: reference_games,
                         label_method: lambda { |obj| obj[0] },
                         value_method: lambda { |obj| "#{ obj[0] } vs #{ obj[1] }".gsub( ' vs ', ',' ) },
                         label: 'Choose a game' %>

        <%= f.input :user_guess, collection: [ 1, 2 ],
                  label_method: lambda { |obj| "Team #{ obj }"},
                  value_method: lambda { |obj| obj },
                  label: 'Who do you think will win?',
                  as: :radio_buttons%>
      <%= f.input :game_type_id, :as => :hidden, :input_html => { :value => 2 } %>
        <br>
        <%= f.submit 'Simulate!', class: 'btn btn-large btn-primary'%>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Here is the code for `application.html.erb`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
    <!--#<title><%= full_title(yield(:title)) %></title>  #TODO: Make custom titles work-->
    <title>Shoulak Predictions</title>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all" %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= render 'layouts/shim' %>    
  </head>
  <body>
    <%= render 'layouts/header' %>
    <div class="container">
      <% flash.each do |key, value| %>
        <div class="alert alert-<%= key %>"><%= value %></div>
      <% end %>
      <%= yield %>
      <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
      <%= debug(params) if Rails.env.development? %>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And, finally, here is the code for `_footer.html.erb`:

```
<footer class="footer">
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><%= link_to "About", about_path, class: "class1" %></li>
        <li><%= link_to "Contact", contact_path, class: "class1 " %></li>
    </ul>
    </nav>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the footer render outside of the 'container' `div`

```
  </div>
  <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
  <%= debug(params) if Rails.env.development? %>
</body>
```